# Is it possible to run an application installer in a reversible transaction?

Tags: windows, uninstall, monitoring, installer

I'd like to run a Windows installer (`.exe`, `.msi`) in such a way that I can see precisely what files, registry keys, and anything else it has added/touched/deleted. Preferably have an easy option to undo these things manually.

[ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) would somewhat support this workflow but there's no way to easily "undo". 
[RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) or similar would allow uninstalling an application thoroughly but would not show a list of files/keys touched.

Running the installer in a VM, monitoring with ProcessMonitor, then restoring a snapshot would be one workflow that achieves this.

Comment: Up until windows XP SP2, there used to be a lovely app called winpooch that would do this. I used to use Altaris SVS (which became SVW) for application virtualisation, and that might be one way to solve this.